# I have installed "mactex" (because I need "pdflatex") but it looks like not opening/working

Tags: pdftex, mac, mactex

I have installed `mactex` because I need `pdflatex`:

```
MyName-MacBook-Pro:~ namesurname$ brew install --cask mactex
Warning: Cask 'mactex' is already installed.

To re-install mactex, run:
  brew reinstall --cask mactex
MyName-MacBook-Pro:~ namesurname$
```

but once I type `mactex` or `which pdflatex` on my terminal it says "command not found" for the first and nothing for the second, respectively:

```
MyName-MacBook-Pro:~ namesurname$ mactex
-bash: mactex: command not found
MyName-MacBook-Pro:~ namesurname$ which pdflatex
MyName-MacBook-Pro:~ namesurname$
```

How can I use/open `mactex` and/or `pdflatex` ??

Comment: Mactex  is only the installer. It set up two things : the texlive tex distribution,  including the pdflatex executable  and the texshop editor. You should run the latter to edit your code, and it will invoke the former when pressing on "compile" or "compose" or "typeset".

Comment: There's no real need to install MacTeX via `homebrew`; it's simpler to install it using the [MacTeX installer package](https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html). This may or may not be the source of your problem, because as I understand it the `homebrew` cask just runs the regular MacTeX install package. But if you've installed it correctly `which pdflatex` should return `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex`. I would uninstall the `homebrew` version and use the package installer in the link I suggested.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone! Thanks @AlanMunn, I followed your instructions in this order, (1) ```brew uninstall mactex```, (2) download ```MacTeX.pkg``` from [MacTex website](https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html) and it works! If I type ```which pdflatex``` from my Terminal, I get the following:
```/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution provided by @AlanMunn in the comments:

1. `brew uninstall mactex`,
2. download `MacTeX.pkg` from [MacTex website](https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html)

Now, if I type `which pdflatex` from my Terminal, I get the following:
`/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex`

Thanks a lot Alan Munn!!!

Answer (score 1):

I was using beamer on mac. I find a similar solution provided by @Ommo above, but:

- MacTex is huge (5.2G now)
- BasicTex is a more popular alternative for `pdflatex`
- Use `brew install basictex` to install BasicTex with HomeBrew
- Make sure `/Library/TeX/texbin` is in your `$PATH`

What I missing was the last step, but this solution still worth mentioning.

Comment: My understanding is that BasicTeX includes pdflatex.  BasicTeX is a small subset of MacTeX, which is a version of the full installation.  BasicTeX is much smaller because it only includes the common executables, packages, and classes.

Comment: Again, it's better to install MacTeX or BasicTeX directly rather than with Homebrew. The BasicTeX installer can be found [here](https://tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html). I wouldn't call it a "more popular alternative"; it's simply a very trimmed down version of MacTeX which excludes all the documentation, and lots of packages, and doesn't install Ghostscript or any of the GUI programs that MacTeX installs. So it's a good choice if you know what you're doing, but for beginners, the full MacTeX install is a better choice.